# How does .NET determine the week in a TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime?

Tags: c#

Greetings

I'm trying to do some DateTime math for various time zones and I wanted to take daylight savings into account.  Lets say I have a TimeZoneInfo and i've determined the appropriate AdjustmentRule for a given DateTime.  Lets also say the particular TimeZoneInfo i'm dealing with is specified as rule.DaylightTransitionStart.IsFixedDateRule == false, so I need to figure out if the given DateTime falls within the start/end TransitionTime.Week values.

This is where I'm getting confused, what is .NET considering as a "week"?  My first thought was it probably used something like

```
DayOfWeek thisMarksWeekBoundaries = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
```

and went through the calendar assigning days to week, incrementing week every time it crossed a boundary.  But, if I do this for May 2010 there are 6 week boundary buckets, and the max valid value for TransitionTime.Week is 5 so this can't be right.

Whats the right way to slice up May 2010?

Comment: Could you give details about what you mean by "6 week boundary buckets"?

Comment: I think I've figured out the answer to my original question, but I'll elaborate on what my thinking was.  I sort of imagined time as this infinite set of days extending back and forth, and for a given culture the value ...DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek denoted when a week ended/began.  The concept of month is another way of grouping this infinite set of days, and within a given month there will be some intersection with the set of weeks.  The buckets i was thinking of were (for lack of a better concept) the unique identifiers for the set of weeks that intersected with the month. days(bucket)<=7

Answer (score 1):

I finally realized whats going on, I think the property name "Week" is what threw me off.  There might be 6 weeks in May (depending on how you count them), but any particular DayOfWeek shows up at most 5 times.  The Week property doesn't really refer to what week the DayOfWeek is showing up in, its the nth DayOfWeek for that month--with the magic value 5 meaning its last so either the max n is 4 or 5 for a given month.